# Stateful Java Web Services and .NET Client

Tags: java, .net, web-services

Please provide a sample stateful webservice in java which would be accible in both java and .net clients.

Answer (score 0):

https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/Maintaining_State_in_Web_Services.html